# Ajax post to the same .php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Got some problems with Ajax calls. My program makes dynamic fields based on user choice. For example, if the user selects "dvd" the Javascript creates a field to add DVD size, or if furniture is selected it creates 3 fields to add h*w*l parameters.

Posting from HTML forms works great but I can't get data to get from jQuery to PHP. Could you help me to post DVD parameter with Ajax?

```
    <?php

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

    ob_clean();



    include('connect_mysql.php');
    $message='error';

    if( isset( $_POST['price'], $_POST['sku'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['prtype'], $_POST['dvd'], $_POST['book'], $_POST['furnh'], $_POST['furnw'], $_POST['furnl'] ) ) {

        $sku = $_POST['sku'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $prtype = $_POST['prtype'];
        $dvd = $_POST['dvd'];
        $book = $_POST['book'];
        $furnh = $_POST['furnh'];
        $furnw = $_POST['furnw'];
        $furnl = $_POST['furnl'];

        $sql = "insert into `people` ( `sku`, `name`, `price`, `prtype`, `dvd`, `book`, `furnh`, `furnw`, `furnl`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt=$dbcon->prepare( $sql );
        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss',$sku,$name,$price,$prtype,$dvd,$book,$furnh,$furnw,$furnl);
            $result=$stmt->execute();
            $stmt->free_result();
            $message=$result ? '1 record added' : 'Something went wrong';

        } else {
            $message='Problem preparing sql statement';
        }
    }


    exit( $message );
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit your data</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Insert your data</h1>

<form method="post" action="training.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Product</legend>
        <label>ID:<input type="text" name="sku"/></label>
        <label>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></label>
        <label>Price:<input type="text" name="price"/></label>
        <label>Product Type</label>
        <select id="Product_Type" name="prtype">
            <option style="display: none;" selected>Select product type</option>
            <option value="Dvd">DVD</option>
            <option value="Book">Book</option>
            <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <br  />
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="add" value="add new product"/>

    <script>

        var $input_DVD = $('<input id="dvd" input type="text" name="dvd" class="input" placeholder="Size"/>');
        var $input_Book = $('<input id="book" input type="text" name="book" class="input" placeholder="Weight"/>');
        var $input_FurnitureHeight = $('<input id="furnh" input type="text" class="input" name="furnh" placeholder="Height"/>');
        var $input_FurnitureWidth = $('<input id="furnw" input type="text" class="input" name="furnw" placeholder="Width"/>');
        var $input_FurnitureLength = $('<input id="furnl" input type="text" class="input" name="furnl"  placeholder="Length"/>');


        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*

                The issue was the generation of a new form with the specific values that
                you are trying to use for adding a new record. The new form was never
                included in the data sent so the logic tests were failing and thus no records
                were ever inserted.

                Some simple debugging using the console would have helped you identify this
                though there still remains the issue of how you deal with form submissions
                when the selected item in the `select` menu is other than DVD!!!

                Using the code here you ought to be able to work that part out now - this works
                for DVD as the selected item

                Rather than insert a new form, it now inserts a new fieldset within the original
                form.

            */

            $('select#Product_Type').on('change', function() {
                $('#container').remove();//<!---- just use the ID

                var val = $(this).val()
                $container = $('<fieldset id="container" ></fieldset>');//  <!---- fieldset, not form

                if (val == "Dvd")$input_DVD.appendTo($container);
                if (val == "Book")$input_Book.appendTo($container);
                if (val == "Furniture"){
                    $input_FurnitureHeight.appendTo($container);
                    $input_FurnitureWidth.appendTo($container);
                    $input_FurnitureLength.appendTo($container);
                }
                $container.insertAfter($(this)).val();
            })
        });

        $(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'POST',
                    url         : location.href,    //  <!---- POST to same page
                    data        : $(this).serialize(),  //  <!---- send all data from this form
                    dataType    : 'json',
                    encode      : true
                })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $('#result').html( data );
                    })
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My database:
[image]

[image]

[image]

P.S Edited code , added code to add all options

Comment: What does it mean that you "can't get data to get from jquery to PHP"? Is sending the AJAX request the problem? Are parameters missing in the request? Do you have problems reading the data in PHP?

Comment: Looks like the only data you are sending with form submit is `dvd`... try `data  : $(this).serialize() ,` instead.

Comment: End your php condition with `exit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only briefly looked through the bulk of the html so may have missed errors in there but to POST, via AJAX, to the same file needs a little careful attention to the portion of code that handles the request. Without care your request would return the entire document - not usually the desired state of affairs so isolate that portion of code and surround with `ob_clean()` to erase any html/other content before that point finish with `exit`

The callback function of the ajax request should process the response - in your case you wished to add to an element with id `result`.

The sql previously was vulnerable to sql injection - so I show how to use a prepared statement below. None of the below has been tested so excuse syntax errors...

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

        ob_clean();



        include('connect_mysql.php');
        $message='error';

        if( isset( $_POST['price'], $_POST['sku'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['prtype'], $_POST['dvd'] ) ) {

            $sku = $_POST['sku'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $prtype = $_POST['prtype'];
            $dvd = $_POST['dvd'];

            $sql = "insert into `people` ( `sku`, `name`, `price`, `prtype`, `dvd`) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt=$dbcon->prepare( $sql );
            if( $stmt ){

                $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$sku,$name,$price,$prtype,$dvd );
                $result=$stmt->execute();
                $stmt->free_result();
                $message=$result ? '1 record added' : 'Something went wrong';

            } else {
                $message='Problem preparing sql statement';
            }
        }


        exit( $message );
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit your data</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Insert your data</h1>

        <form method="post" action="training.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

            <fieldset>
                <legend>New Product</legend>
                <label>ID:<input type="text" name="sku"/></label>
                <label>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></label>
                <label>Price:<input type="text" name="price"/></label>
                <label>Product Type</label>
                <select id="Product_Type" name="prtype">
                    <option style="display: none;" selected>Select product type</option>
                    <option value="Dvd">DVD</option>
                    <option value="Book">Book</option>
                    <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <br  />
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="add" value="add new product"/>

            <script>

                var $input_DVD = $('<input id="dvd" input type="text" name="dvd" class="input" placeholder="Size"/>');
                var $input_Book = $('<input id="book" input type="text" name="book" class="input" placeholder="Weight"/>');
                var $input_FurnitureHeight = $('<input id="furnh" input type="text" class="input" name="furnh" placeholder="Height"/>');
                var $input_FurnitureWidth = $('<input id="furnw" input type="text" class="input" name="furnw" placeholder="Width"/>');
                var $input_FurnitureLength = $('<input id="furnl" input type="text" class="input" name="furnl"  placeholder="Length"/>');


                $(document).ready(function() {
                    /*

                        The issue was the generation of a new form with the specific values that
                        you are trying to use for adding a new record. The new form was never 
                        included in the data sent so the logic tests were failing and thus no records
                        were ever inserted.

                        Some simple debugging using the console would have helped you identify this
                        though there still remains the issue of how you deal with form submissions 
                        when the selected item in the `select` menu is other than DVD!!! 

                        Using the code here you ought to be able to work that part out now - this works
                        for DVD as the selected item

                        Rather than insert a new form, it now inserts a new fieldset within the original
                        form.

                    */

                    $('select#Product_Type').on('change', function() {
                        $('#container').remove();//<!---- just use the ID

                        var val = $(this).val()
                        $container = $('<fieldset id="container" ></fieldset>');//  <!---- fieldset, not form

                        if (val == "Dvd")$input_DVD.appendTo($container);
                        if (val == "Book") $input_Book.appendTo($container);

                        if (val == "Furniture"){
                            $input_FurnitureHeight.appendTo($container);
                            $input_FurnitureWidth.appendTo($container);
                            $input_FurnitureLength.appendTo($container);
                        }
                        $container.insertAfter($(this)).val();
                    })
                })

                $(function() {
                    $('form').submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type        : 'POST',
                            url         : location.href,    //  <!---- POST to same page
                            data        : $(this).serialize(),  //  <!---- send all data from this form
                            dataType    : 'json',
                            encode      : true
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            $('#result').html( data );
                        })
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </form>
        <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still no records are made into sql... When i press submit button it doesn't reload page , maybe problems are there ?

Comment: I don't use jQuery so the ajax function is the first place to investigate - check the console to see if the request gets sent at all. My answer was primarily to address the issue of sending a request to the same page and how you deal with that.

Comment: After creating a table in my db and running this as a test - I found the issue... The select menu generates a new form with whatever is the selected item as a field ( or selection of fields ).... That new form is NOT part of any submitted data

Comment: Dvd works great, but can you explain why another options are not working? I've added "book" option to php part (you can see it in my post) but cant figure why its not working. Nothing extra is added to dvd option part , so it's confuses it's working, but rest of options are not.

Comment: so you added another column to the query for `book` - what about `furniture`? Presumably there is a column ( or 3 ) in the same table to deal with that? Knowing the table schema would be handy

Comment: Edited code,added database, that's how it should be working in my opinion. Now it's not working as well(not even dvd option),but if i delete book and furniture it's starts working again.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'POST',
                    url         : 'training.php',  // post to same file
                    data        : $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType    : 'json',
                    encode      : true
                })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    })
            });
```

Comment: try this     $('select#Product_Type').on('change', function() {
                        $('form#container').remove();
                        var val = $(this).val()
                        $container = $('<div id="container" ></div>');

Comment: use div inspite of form again and i dont find where is you element id=result div

Answer (score 2):

As it is quite different to the original answer and because the question has mutated a little I felt it might be clearer to add as another answer. Because the original question just revolved around the `dvd` being added  a rethink was required to accomodate other columns and data for the insert statement. The following has not been tested but replaces the original ajax handling php code.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

        ob_clean();

        /* my test db conn */
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root'; 
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $dbcon  =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

        #include('connect_mysql.php');

        $message='error';

        if( isset( $_POST['price'], $_POST['sku'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['prtype'] ) ) {
            /* Do some filtering of the POSTed variables */
            $args=array(
                'sku'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'name'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'price'     =>  array(
                    'filter'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
                    'flags'     => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND
                ),
                'prtype'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'dvd'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'book'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'furnh'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'furnw'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'furnl'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            );
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            /* extract the POST data into variables */
            extract( $_POST );

            /* a one-for-all query, insert empty strings where suitable */
            $sql = "insert into `people` ( `sku`, `name`, `price`, `prtype`, `dvd`, `book`, `furnh`, `furnw`, `furnl` ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt= $dbcon->prepare( $sql );

            if( $stmt ){

                $stmt->bind_param('ssdssssss', $sku, $name, $price, $prtype, $dvd, $book, $furnh, $furnw, $furnl );

                if( !empty( $_POST['dvd'] ) ){
                    /* dvd only: set empty values for other parameters/vars */
                    $book = $furnh = $funw = $furnl = '';

                } elseif( !empty( $_POST['book'] ) ){
                    /* books: set empty values for other parameters/vars */
                    $dvd = $furnh = $funw = $furnl = '';

                } elseif( isset( $_POST['furnw'],$_POST['furnl'],$_POST['furnh'] ) ){
                    /* furniture: set empty values for other parameters/vars */
                    $book = $dvd = '';
                }

                $result=$stmt->execute();
                $stmt->free_result();
                $message=$result ? '1 record added' : 'Something went wrong';

            } else {
                $message='Problem preparing sql statement';
            }

            exit( $message );
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit your data</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Insert your data</h1>

        <form method="post" action="training.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

            <fieldset>
                <legend>New Product</legend>
                <label>ID:<input type="text" name="sku"/></label>
                <label>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></label>
                <label>Price:<input type="text" name="price"/></label>
                <label>Product Type</label>
                <select id="Product_Type" name="prtype">
                    <option style="display: none;" selected>Select product type</option>
                    <option value="Dvd">DVD</option>
                    <option value="Book">Book</option>
                    <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <br  />
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="add" value="add new product"/>

            <script>

                var $input_DVD = $('<input id="dvd" input type="text" name="dvd" class="input" placeholder="Size"/>');
                var $input_Book = $('<input id="book" input type="text" name="book" class="input" placeholder="Weight"/>');
                var $input_FurnitureHeight = $('<input id="furnh" input type="text" class="input" name="furnh" placeholder="Height"/>');
                var $input_FurnitureWidth = $('<input id="furnw" input type="text" class="input" name="furnw" placeholder="Width"/>');
                var $input_FurnitureLength = $('<input id="furnl" input type="text" class="input" name="furnl"  placeholder="Length"/>');


                $(document).ready(function() {
                    /*

                        The issue was the generation of a new form with the specific values that
                        you are trying to use for adding a new record. The new form was never 
                        included in the data sent so the logic tests were failing and thus no records
                        were ever inserted.

                        Some simple debugging using the console would have helped you identify this
                        though there still remains the issue of how you deal with form submissions 
                        when the selected item in the `select` menu is other than DVD!!! 

                        Using the code here you ought to be able to work that part out now - this works
                        for DVD as the selected item

                        Rather than insert a new form, it now inserts a new fieldset within the original
                        form.

                    */

                    $('select#Product_Type').on('change', function() {
                        $('#container').remove();//<!---- just use the ID

                        var val = $(this).val()
                        $container = $('<fieldset id="container" ></fieldset>');//  <!---- fieldset, not form

                        if (val == "Dvd")$input_DVD.appendTo($container);
                        if (val == "Book") $input_Book.appendTo($container);

                        if (val == "Furniture"){
                            $input_FurnitureHeight.appendTo($container);
                            $input_FurnitureWidth.appendTo($container);
                            $input_FurnitureLength.appendTo($container);
                        }
                        $container.insertAfter($(this)).val();
                    })
                })

                $(function() {
                    $('form').submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type        : 'POST',
                            url         : location.href,    //  <!---- POST to same page
                            data        : $(this).serialize(),  //  <!---- send all data from this form
                            dataType    : 'json',
                            encode      : true
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            $('#result').html( data );
                        })
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </form>
        <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The db schema

```
mysql> describe people;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sku    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| prtype | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dvd    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| book   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| furnw  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| furnl  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| furnh  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql> select * from people;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

> **Adding DVD**
>   [image: DVD]
>
> **Adding a book**
>   [image: Book]
>
> **Adding furniture**
>   [image: Furniture]

```
mysql> select * from people;
+--------+--------------+-------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| sku    | name         | price | prtype    | dvd  | book | furnw | furnl | furnh |
+--------+--------------+-------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 78459  | Geronimo     | 0     | Dvd       | 55   |      | NULL  |       |       |
| 123456 | pocahontas   | 7845  | Book      |      | 5632 | NULL  |       |       |
| 78     | chief wiggum | 0     | Furniture |      |      | 20    | 30    | 10    |
+--------+--------------+-------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Not getting any records into DB, even when i delete every column after dvd and code responsible for book and furniture it not posting any data. Maybe posting to separate file will be better for such task? I'm really confused why POST doesn't work, especially when one option is posted but 2 other are not , despite implementation for options are kinda the same.

Comment: I just rattled this up as a test - worked fine. I'll edit the above with the FULL code used for the demo - though the db connection I used will be redacted but you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Admittedly I can see a slight error - where the price was a decimal it returns 0 / false ~ the expected behaviour for `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` - a more rigourous $args array with some flags set should alleviate that if filtering is to remain.

Comment: Change the `i` in the `bind_param('ssi...` to a `d` ~ `bind_param('ssd...`

Comment: Looks like php submits everything fine , problem is with my database connection , connection params are 100% right, but i'm still getting Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: are you actually using `mysqli` in the db connection and not PDO? The error message seems quite explicit so tht has to be worth further investigation. Also- just spotted the jQuery/ajax function has it's datatype set to json but the response from the php is basic plain text.

Answer (score 1):

In You ajax call you are specifying dataTyp:'json'.Then you Should return json data from php. And Instead of exit you should use return.

```
      return json_encode(@utf8_encode($message));
//or
      return json_encode($message);
```